# CURL in JAVA - Could not resolve host : POST

Tags: java, post, curl, httpclient, processbuilder

I have been successfully able to perform CURL commands from the CMD in my Windows PC by installing curl for Windows. Similarly, I have been able to get them working in my JAVA application by using ProcessBuilder and Process to create Operating System process. In particular, I need to execute the REST API end point commands used in KissFlow given here: https://support.kissflow.com/support/solutions/articles/179582-understanding-the-rest-api-end-points

Question: I have been able to able to execute the commands with the GET method like so.
`ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("curl","-H","api_key:<XXXX>","-X","GET","http://<XXXX>.appspot.com/api/1/Employee/list/p1/50`

However, when using the commands with POST like
`ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("curl","-H","api_key:<XXXX>","-X ","POST","--data-urlencode","First Name=XXXX","http://<XXXX>.appspot.com/api/1/Employee/submit");`, I get an error: 
*curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST*
with the input stream of the process returning
`<html><title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title></html>`

This in fact works perfectly when executed from CMD.

I have tried suggestions of all related questions here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**: Any alternate method from CURL to do the same will be acceptable as well.

Comment: Side note: avoid spawning external tools in Java if possible. Commons::HttpClient can do from plain Java!

Comment: Exactly as @GyroGearless said, use HttpRequest instead of curl. Using curl in java is really unpleasant ;-)

Comment: I haven't exactly tried out HttpClient. Can you please post the correct way to use that for the above commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According @GyroGearless's idea, try to use the sample code below to retrieve responses from URLs through methods GET and POST using Apache's HttpClient class. I think that with HttpClient you'll have much more "power" than with CURL.

You'll need *commons-httpclient.jar* and its dependencies: *commons-codec* and *commons-logging*. You'll find these jars at http://commons.apache.org/downloads/

```
(...)
String url = "http://<XXXX>.appspot.com/api/1/Employee/list/p1/50";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
GetMethod get = new GetMethod(url);
client.executeMethod(get);
System.out.println(new String(get.getResponseBody()));
get.releaseConnection();

url = "http://<XXXX>.appspot.com/api/1/Employee/submit";
PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);
post.addParameter("id", "10");
client.executeMethod(post);
System.out.println(new String(post.getResponseBody()));
post.releaseConnection();
(...)
```

As you can see, in the PostMethod part we're sending parameters within request. Maybe you don't need this....

Comment: I just had to use the addRequestHeader method as well and it works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Visual studio, we also created a post method where we reject requests in kissflow. Just letting you know that you can also do that in visual studio.